# static_assert in std::conditional

Tags: c++, templates

In the following reduced SSCCE why does the static assertion fail?

Obviously this is because the compiler attempts to instantiate `Assert<i - 8>`, which for unsigned `size_t` results in an astronomical `index` template argument. But why does it try to instantiate this and what can I do about it?

```
#include <utility>

struct Struct {
    template<size_t index>
    struct Assert {
        static_assert(index < 8, "xxx");
        using Type = int;
    };
};


template<size_t i>
using Test = typename std::conditional<
    (i < 8),
    typename Struct::template Assert<i>::Type,
    typename Struct::template Assert<i - 8>::Type
>::type;

Test<0> t;
```

Comment: `std::conditional` isn't "lazy". To instantiate a template `V<T, U>` you need to instantiate `T` and `U` first, even if they don't end up being used. You could solve that with something like this https://ideone.com/urMBjB (but that requires you to create new templates for each choice). In that specific case, you could also just use `i < 8 ? i : i - 8`